# C Bouncing Ball Gives Error

Tags: c

I'm making a program that bounces a ball with C. I'm using the Stanford Portable Library to do it: ball is a GOval. This code should successfully bounce the ball, but when I run it, it says, "error: getX: Illegal argument type" The following is the only usage thus far of getX():

```
if (getX(ball) + getWidth(ball) >= getWidth(window))
    {
        velocityx = -velocityx;
    } 
else if (getX(ball) <= 0)
    {
        velocityx = -velocityx;
    }
```

I don't understand how this could be an error, getX returns the X location of a GObject, which ball is.
I can't use anything other than C or GObjects, this is for a class.
The example code of a bouncing ball [here](http://pastebin.com/45L8cMM2) given by the instructor works.

Comment: What data type is "ball"?  What data type is getX() expecting?  They don't match.

Comment: You are passing a `ball` object that is a type that doesn't match your `getX(...)`; function.

Comment: @Happington getX() expects a GObject, no? And ball is a GOval, which is a GObject.

Comment: Show us the declaration of `ball` and the prototypes of your functions. I expect you are confused about c data types, conflating them with the concept of an object from another language.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `-getWidth(ball)` in the second conditional, and using `< 0` not `<= 0`? And if the answer from @Tarik is correct, something like `ball.width` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Having looked up the online reference of the Stanford C++ library, a GOval is a subclass of GObject wich has a getX() method. As such it should use `ball.getX ()`

See http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/